# How change Navigationcontrollers title

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a navigation controller that is linked to a tabbarcontroller with three tabs. I like to change the title for each tab. I have tried

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Contacts"
navigationItem.title = "Contacts"
```

for the first tab the title is shown, but when changing to another tab, the title of this tab is not shown, the title remains the one from the first tab.

I am using Xcode 9 and Swift. Running on real device and simulator with the same result.

Comment: So do you have tabbar controller pushed into a navigation controller? Or do you have navigation controller as one of the tabs in tabbar controller?

Comment: I have the tabbar controller as part of the navigation controller.

Comment: In each view controller which are binded to the tab bar controller implement viewWillAppear method and write into it:  
self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "some title"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this in your ViewController

```
self.title = "YOUR TITLE"
```

Comment: Thanks. with the response from Graham and Hassan Javed, got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have separate classes for each of your View controller add this code to viewWillAppear method:

```
self.tabBarController?.title  = "Your view title"
```

`self.tabBarController?.title` changes the navigation bar title whereas `self.title` changes the tabbar item's title.